# Strange gap at the bottom of the HTML video element, when using object-fit: cover;

Tags: css, google-chrome, html5-video, cover, object-fit

In some cases, when one of the parent elements in HTML is having `margin` of `padding` defined at the bottom or at the top, it will happen that your `video` object can't stretch the source media to the fullest within itself. Even if you define the `object-fit:cover` you will still have the small gap at the top or the bottom of the `video` tag. This is happening only in Google Chrome as far as I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, setting `display: block;` on video element solved the issue.

Comment: It worked, but I still get 1px bellow.
Better than before.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that helped me solve this issue is to set the `object-position: top` or `object-position: bottom;` on the `video` tag. It depends where the gap is.